# Reading Pcap files with tcmpdump pcap through C++ reads the packet correctly, but not the timestamp

Tags: c++, timestamp, libpcap, packet-capture, winpcap

i was reading a pcap file using pcap_open_offline() and pcap_loop().
The packets are read correctly.

But in the pcap_loop function, header->ts.tv_sec gives me the current timestamp( I checked the value in internet and it showed me my current time, and not the time when the packet was captured ).

However, wireshark displays the correct time when it was captured, if we open the pcap file through Wireshark. I am using windows.

Here is parts of my code

```
pcap_t* descr;
    char errbuf2[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];

    // open capture file for offline processing
    descr = pcap_open_offline(t->file, errbuf2);
    if (descr == NULL) {
        printf("pcap_open_live() failed: %s\n", errbuf2);
        return 1;
    }

    // start packet processing loop, just like live capture
    if (pcap_loop(descr, 0, packetHandler, (u_char*)&actors[a]) < 0) {
        printf("pcap_loop() failed:%s ", pcap_geterr(descr));
        return 1;
    }
```

```
void packetHandler(u_char* args, const struct pcap_pkthdr* header, const u_char* pkt)
{
   //----------
printf("% ld \n", header->ts.tv_sec);
//---------
}
```

Comment: So, in Wireshark, you selected "Seconds since 1970-01-01" from View -> Time Display Format, and the number Wireshark showed before the decimal place in the Time column for the *N*th packet didn't match the value your program printed for the *N*th packet?

Comment: hello sir, the problem was solved by ```pcap_open_offline_with_tstamp_precision(t->file,
  PCAP_TSTAMP_PRECISION_MICRO, errbuf2);

Comment: That has no effect on the `tv_sec` field, only on the `tv_usec` field - it causes the `tv_usec` field to be in nanoseconds, rather than microseconds.  (Yes, that's confusing, given that "usec" refers to "microseconds", but that's what the current libpcap API requires.)